# DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE not giving output when the SQL have DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML

Tags: oracle

I am generating a dynamic SQL which generates XML data, using SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML, as the output have special characters,
which are not supported in XML. I tried and tested SQL in separately, It is working as expected.
I am not able to fetch the data, when I call it using Dynamic SQL.

I have used DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB2 as it is treating whole SQL starting  DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML as one column.

--Snippet

Declaration

```
SelectCursorId          NUMBER;                 --For Dynamic SQL binding
RowProcessed                INTEGER;                --For Dynamic SQL binding
MstrSeqNbr              NUMBER  := 1;
ColumnCount             NUMBER;                 --For Dynamic SQL binding
RecordSqrNbr                NUMBER  := 0;           --For Dynamic SQL binding
ColumnDescTbl           DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB2;     --dbms_sql.desc_tab2 
ColumnValue             VARCHAR2(4000);         --For Dynamic SQL binding
DymanicSQLCols          VARCHAR2(4000);         -- For debugging purpose, columns returned 
SelectSQL               VARCHAR2(6000);

BEGIN

--Snippet

SelectSQL :=   'SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT MRQ.BatchNBR AS Batch_NUMBER, 
                                                MRQ.BatchRUNSEQNBR AS Batch_RUN_INSTANCE, 
                                                        MRQ.BatchRUNDATE AS RUN_DATE, 
                                                        MRQ.SPDATE AS POST_DATE, 
                                                        MRQ.BatchNAME AS Batch_NAME, 
                                                        MRQ.RPTNAME AS DATABASE_NAME, 
                                                        MRQ.EFFDATE AS RUN_TIME, 
                                                        MRQ.BatchSTARTDATE AS ELAPSED_TIME , 
                                                        CURSOR ( SELECT MRI.MSTREPORTRECSEQNBR AS RECORD_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, 
                                                                    MRI.RTTEXT1VC100 AS COUNTRY_NAME, 
                                                                    MRI.RTTEXT2VC100 AS CURRENCY_USED, 
                                                                    MRI.RTTEXT1VC50 AS COUNTRY_SHORT_CODE, 
                                                                    MRI.RTNUM1P0 AS ISO_CURRENCY_CODE 
                                                                  FROM MasterReporting MRI 
                                                                  WHERE BatchNbr = MR.BatchNbr 
                                                                  AND BatchRUNSEQNBR = MR.BatchRUNINSTANCE 
                                                                  ORDER BY MSTREPORTRECSEQNBR )Record 
                                                  FROM BatchRUNHIST MR , MastRptSeqDtl MRQ 
                                                   WHERE MR.BatchNbr =  100 
                                                   AND MR.BatchRUNINSTANCE IN( 67) 
                                                   AND MRQ.BatchRUNSEQNBR = MR.BatchRUNINSTANCE 
                                                   AND MR.BatchRunStatCD =''COMPL'' 
                                      ')
                    FROM DUAL ';



SelectCursorId := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;                                 --Pass

DBMS_SQL.PARSE ( SelectCursorId, SelectSQL, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);           --Pass

DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2( SelectCursorId, ColumnCount, ColumnDescTbl);  --Pass

** However ColumnDescTbl(1).col_name is only giving following, not sure if this is the issue 

DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT MRQ.BatchNBRASBatch_NUMBER, MRQ.BatchRUNSEQNBRASBatch_RUN_INSTANCE, MRQ.BatchRUNDATEASRUN_DATE, MRQ.SPDATEASPOST_DATE, MRQ.BatchNAMEASBatch_NAME, MRQ.RPTNAMEASDATABAS

Next step also passes

For k in 1..ColumnCount LOOP   
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SelectCursorId, k, ColumnValue, 4000);     --Pass
END LOOP;


RowProcessed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(SelectCursorId);         
--Passes but gives 0 as output,
--Whereas, running the SQL separately gives you one row of XML data.
```

Minimum One row of XML Data should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [`dbms_sql.execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-D4F4030F-09B4-4337-BDDD-9B5A6BCEDED2):

> The return value is only valid for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements; for other types of statements, including DDL, the return value is undefined and must be ignored.

As your statement is a `select` the `RowProcessed` return value has no meaning; it isn't significant that you're seeing zero there.

You need to do a `fetch_rows` step after that, or change it to [`execute_and_fetch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-415CE3C0-575C-4F7A-8471-11D584E3ED4F). Either way you then need to process the fetched data, of course.

(The `col_name` looks like a non-issue, it's just an automatically generated name/alias. If you change your dynamic statement to do `...) AS my_col_alias FROM DUAL` then the `col_name` will be reported as `MY_COL_ALIAS`.)

Comment: Thanks Alex, using the alias the first issue is resolved, I no longer need to use DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2, 

regarding the second issue, I have started using DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE_and_Fetch, which was initially not giving 
me any value. I made a slight change i.e. the width of column from 4000 to 32767 (Max length VARCHAR2)in 
 DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SelectCursorId, 1, ColumnValue, 32767); 

and now RowProcessed has started giving me value =1 as expected 

 RowProcessed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE_and_fetch(SelectCursorId); 

I am still working on the fetch part, I will be sharing the results.